# PostGIS with Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, geometry, postgis

For some reason, using ST_Intersects in Laravel gives error:

```
Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function st_intersects(public.geometry, public.geometry) does not exist
```

Exactly same query, with same DB is working perfectly fine in plain PHP.

Full query text:

```
$query =
       "SELECT estado, municipio, COUNT(*)
        FROM public.focos_bdq, dados_geo.poligonos_deter
        WHERE ST_Intersects(focos_bdq.geometria, poligonos_deter.geom)
        AND bioma LIKE '$bioma_bd'
        AND date_trunc('month', data_hora_gmt)::date = '$mes_anterior'
        AND (satelite LIKE 'AQUA%' OR satelite LIKE 'TERRA%')
        GROUP BY municipio, estado
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";

$focos = \DB::select($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should append the schema name (postgis) to the function name.
    postgis.ST_Intersects(...

Alternatively the user that laravel logs in with might need to have its schema search path set properly.

Comment: Unfortunately appending schema didn't help.  How can I verify laravel user?

Comment: I just meant the DB user that laravel is using to login to the DB, would be in the DB config file. Also, can you log the sql either by turning on PG logging or by using the laravel logger and capture the sql sent to the DB?